# Problem with an array function in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to make a small shell script function where basically it should return me only the two latest versions of a github repository (not counting the latest).
Here is my code:

```
get_release() {
curl --silent \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/releases |
  grep '"tag_name":' |
  sed -E 's/.*"([^"]+)".*/\1/' 
}

#str="1.1.1 2.2.2 3.3.3 4.4.4 5.5.5 6.6.6 7.7.7 8.8.8 9.9.9"
str=($get_release)

#VERSION=$(get_release)
IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< "$str"

LASTVERSION=${array[-2]}
PENULTIMATEVERSION=${array[-3]}

echo "${LASTVERSION}"
echo "${PENULTIMATEVERSION}"
```

But I'm getting this when I try to run:

```
t.sh: line 17: array: bad array subscript
t.sh: line 18: array: bad array subscript
```

Note: the commented str variable is just a simulation of an array, with it working normally, but when trying to use the get_release function, I get this error.

Comment: You'll get that error if there aren't enough values in the array. What does `declare -p str array` show?

Comment: Try `str=($(get_release))`

Comment: `declare -p str array` return this:

`t.sh: line 23: declare: v2.2.4: not found
t.sh: line 23: declare: v2.2.3: not found
t.sh: line 23: declare: v2.2.2: not found
t.sh: line 23: declare: v2.2.1: not found
t.sh: line 23: declare: v2.2.0: not found
t.sh: line 23: declare: v2.1.0: not found
t.sh: line 23: declare: v2.0.0: not found`

Comment: @Philippe

`str=($(get_release))`  It had no effect, same error.

Comment: It should have effect. `str` is already an array. You don't need `IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< "$str"`

Comment: @Philippe I know, but the point is that `str` is just an example for testing, the real function should be `get_release`.

Comment: @Philippe, please **don't** encourage people to populate arrays with string splitting. It has unintended side effects such as glob expansion -- the `read -r -a` approach is the Right Thing.

Comment: ...see [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_.2BICY.29_.29) going into detail.

Comment: @Fernando, negative indices aren't universally available. Which _specific_ version of bash are you using here?

Comment: @Fernando, ...in general, it's safer to use something like `${array[$(( ${#array[@]} - 1 ))]}` to refer to a position relative to the end.

Comment: Also, **please** don't try to parse JSON with `grep` and `sed`. It's very much an exercise doomed to end in pain the moment github changes a library version and starts emitting one-line output instead of pretty-printed content from its API.

Answer (score 1):

As a working example which is compatible with all bash releases from 3.2 forward:

```
get_releases() {
  local user=$1 repo=$2
  curl --silent \
    -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
    "https://api.github.com/repos/$user/$repo/releases" |
    jq -r '.[].tag_name'
}

IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a releases < <(get_releases juji-io datalevin && printf '\0')
echo "Newest release: ${releases[0]}"
echo "Oldest release: ${releases[${#releases[@]}-1]}"
echo "Second oldest:  ${releases[${#releases[@]}-2]}"
```

...which as of present date correctly emits (for the `juji-io/datalevin` project used in the example above):

```
Newest release: 0.6.6
Oldest release: 0.5.13
Second oldest:  0.5.14
```

Answer (score 0):

As per @Philippe's comments `($get_release)` will not call your function, but `$(get_release)` will.

As per @Charles Duffy and @glenn jackman's comments for I've updated the code snippet for safely checking and accessing the last elements of an array.

Here's the amended code snippet:

```sh
get_release() {
curl --silent \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/releases |
  grep '"tag_name":' |
  sed -E 's/.*"([^"]+)".*/\1/' 
}

# str=($get_release) # Warning: this does not call get_release
# str='1.1.1 2.2.2 3.3.3 4.4.4 5.5.5 6.6.6 7.7.7 8.8.8 9.9.9'
str=$(get_release)

IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< "$str"

n=${#array[@]}
((n > 1)) && LASTVERSION=${array[$((n-1))]}
((n > 2)) && PENULTIMATEVERSION=${array[$((n-2))]}

echo "${LASTVERSION}" # 9.9.9
echo "${PENULTIMATEVERSION}" # 8.8.8
```

Here's another solution based on perl, regex, and capture groups, i.e.

```sh
# str=($get_release) # Warning: this does not call get_release
# str='1.1.1 2.2.2 3.3.3 4.4.4 5.5.5 6.6.6 7.7.7 8.8.8 9.9.9'
str=$(get_release)
LASTVERSION=$(perl -ne 'print if s/.* (\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/\1/' <<< $str)
PENULTIMATEVERSION=$(perl -ne 'print if s/.* (\d+\.\d+\.\d+) \d+\.\d+\.\d+/\1/' <<< $str)

echo "${LASTVERSION}" # 9.9.9
echo "${PENULTIMATEVERSION}" # 8.8.8
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the whole of the question. The way the OP is indexing into their array is also broken.

Comment: (whether `${array[-2]}` works to index backwards is _very_ version-dependent; it's not a feature that has been around long enough to be relied on)

Comment: ...also, `set -e` is... _controversial_, to put it kindly. See [the exercises section of BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) illustrating some of the many gotchas it ropes in.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy looks like I have reading to do.

Comment: "not a feature that has been around long enough to be relied on" -- it was introduced in version 4.2, released in 2011. version 4.3 introduces setting and unsetting using a negative index.

Comment: @StephenQuan, the substrict of a numerically-indexed array is evaluated as an arithmetic expression: the `$(())` syntax is not required there: `${array[n - 1]}`

Comment: Also, you might want to test `n` before using `${array[n - 2]}` -- if n == 1, then n - 2 == -1 which is the same as ${array[n - 1]}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who helped me, I was able to solve it this way:

```
get_release() {
curl --silent \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/releases |
  grep '"tag_name":' |
  sed -E 's/.*"([^"]+)".*/\1/' 
}

CREATE_ARRAY=$'\n' read -d "\034" -r -a array <<< "$(get_branch)\034" # See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/628527/split-string-on-newline-and-write-it-into-array-using-read

PENULTIMATE_VERSION="${array[2]}"
ANTIPENULTIMATE_VERSION="${array[1]}"
```